# I don't understand the paragraph about multicast

Tags: sockets, unix, networking

This paragraph if from UNP, 
chapter 21.3 page 555

1. A host running an application that has joined some multicast group whose
   corresponding Ethernet address just happens to be one that the interface
   receives when it is programmed to receive 01:00:5e:00:01:01 (e.e., the
   interface card performs imperfect filtering). This frame will be discarded
   either by datalink layer or by the IP layer.

I just don't know which special case is the author talking about. Could you help me explain it clearly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IN IPV4.  A multicast Address (old class D) consists of 4 bits fixed for identifying it as multicast(1110), and the remaining 28 bits to Identify the group.

Since there are only 23 Bits available in a MAC Address (the high order 25 bits are fixed), when you map the lower order 23 bits of the multicast address into the lower order 23 bits of the mac you lose 5 bits of addressing information.  So multiple Multicast addresses all have the same MAC address.

for example

```
237.138.0.1
238.138.0.1
239.138.0.1
```

all map to MAC address:  01:00:5e:0a:00:01 (There are more, this is just a subset to illustrate)

so if you join group 237.138.0.1, your ethernet card will start sending frames up the stack for that MAC.   Since it is an imperfect match (since we discarded those 5 bits), the ethernet card will also send 238.138.0.1 and 239.138.0.1 up the stack as well.  But since you are not interested in those frames they will be discard at Layer 2 (data link) or Layer 3 (Network) when they can be matched exactly.

So the special case is that if you have multiple multicast streams that occupy the same lower 23 bits of address space, all hosts on the network segment are going to have to process the packets higher up in the stack and thus do more work to tell if the packet they got is one they are interested in).

normally you just need to make sure when planning your multicast deployments, that you try to avoid overlapping addresses.

Comment: Thanks! That is to say, if I need multiple different multicast address, I should change the group id (the lower 23 bits), but not the upper 5 bits (as could be considered as multicast network id).  In short, multicast network couldn't coexist without upper protocol do perfect filtering, right?

Comment: if you need multiple addresses and are just using them locally you should use addresses from 239.0.0.0/8 (as that is admin scoped, to be used within your organizaton). but any address between 224.0.0.0 and 239.255.255.255 is multicast. But yep you just need to make sure that the lower 23 bits are different . 239.239.1.1 , 239.239.1.2, 239.239.1.3 would all work and not overlap, etc...